# Combining highslide with hover effect

Tags: highslide

I have tried to combine 2 scripts together (highslide and a hover effect) so that the thumbnail has a hover effect happen before clicking to have the highslide gallery pop up. All works really well surprisingly as I don't have a lot of experience....but....if I want the pop up gallery images to have the thumbnails under them, its not quite right, it picks up the hover effect and adds it to the small thumbnails under the image.

Is there any way around this. Any help would be appreciated. I am kind of OK at adjusting scripting that is there, very simply but trying to write a new bit of script is beyond me.

Please see URL

http://www.ballinarealestate.info/nok/thumbs/highslide-custom-example.htm

Answer (score 0):

The hover effect appears in the thumbstrip in the gallery since the thumbnail in the thumbstrip actually picks up and use the code from the thumbnail in the page.
To avoid this, you need to use the method described in this FAQ item to open the gallery: http://forum.highcharts.com/highslide-faq/how-do-i-open-a-gallery-from-a-text-link-or-an-image-link-t4372/

Comment: Better link: http://forum.highcharts.com/highslide-faq/how-do-i-open-a-gallery-from-a-text-link-or-an-image-link-t4372/